# How to derive the depth in my image (limit Magnitude )?

Tags: data-analysis, photometry, magnitude

I saw that some survey said that their depth is 27.5 magnitudes.

May I ask that if I have a dataset with magnitude and their errors, for example I have J band `j_m`, `j_cmsig`, `j_msigcom`, `j_snr` from Sextractor.

How can I derive the 3 sigma magnitude depth in this fields to compare with the other survey.

Answer (score 1):

It's the magnitude where the average signal-to-noise ratio (I assume that's what j_snr represents) is 3.

Comment: Is this possible to calculate from j magnitude and their error?

Comment: @GHC No. And notice that magnitude uncertainties are generally non-linear and asymmetric, particularly when large.

Comment: May I ask that what the different if I need to get the depth in 5sigma/2arcsec? So I can plot the SNR and get the SNR to 5, but what the meaning of 2arcsec.